# How to compile HelloJGraphT demo?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jgrapht

I need to use JgraphT to compile and run this https://jgrapht.org/guide/HelloJGraphT

I used command line to create a maven project with jgrapht https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/How-to-use-JGraphT-as-a-dependency-in-your-projects

Then I need to convert it to a gradle project and build. Which I used

gradle init --type java-library --dsl groovy --test-framework junit

can't get it to build. I have the dependency 
compile 'org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.3.0'

Please help, I don't know what I'm missing. Please explain how to build HelloJGraphT Demo in gradle. 
Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot of possibilities. Have you ever build a Gradle project before? If not, there is probably no short answer for this. You need to have Gradle installed in your system. If you know the general Gradle procedure,  then just add the Maven central repository to your repositories as `repositories { mavenCentral() }` and jgrapht as a dependency `dependencies { implementation 'org.jgrapht:jgrapht:1.3.0' } ` in your "build.gradle" file.

Comment: why change it to a gradle project? maven works fine right?